# Instance Member Cannot Be Used On Type - Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

I am new to Swift and I am following a tutorial on how to create a social media app with Xcode and Firebase. However, I got this error:

> Instance member 'database' cannot be used on type 'DatabaseReference'

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class Post {

private var _username: String!
private var _userImg: String!
private var _postImg: String!
private var _likes: Int!
private var _postKey: String!
private var _postRef: DatabaseReference

var username: String {

    return _userImg
}

var postImg: String {
    get {
        return _postImg
    }set {
        _postImg = newValue
    }
}

var likes: Int {
    return _likes
}

var postKey: String {
    return _postKey
}


init(imgUrl: String, likes: Int, username: String, userImg: String) {
    _likes = likes
    _postImg = postImg
    _username = username
    _userImg = userImg
}

init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    _postKey = postKey

    if let username = postData["username"] as? String {
        _username = username
    }

    if let userImg = postData["userImg"] as? String{
        _userImg = userImg
    }

    if let postImage = postData["imageUrl"] as? String {
        _postImg = postImage
    }

    if let likes = postData["likes"] as? Int {
        _likes = likes
    }

_postRef = DatabaseReference.database().reference().child("posts")
}
}
```

I get my error on the third to last line that says:

```
_postRef = DatabaseReference.database().reference().child("posts")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `database` property is an instance type, meaning it must be referenced by an instance of `DatabaseReference`. Your call to `DatabaseReference.database` is accessing for a class, or static, type. You need to change your call to an instance of `DatabaseReference`.

Presumably, you need to initialize an instance of `DatabaseReference`. I don't know Firebase to know what is required for that, but that will take care of your issue.

Essentially:

```
let databaseReference = DatabaseReference() // Likely won't work, but some init method here will
_postRef = databaseReference.database()... // Whatever you need here
```

Comment: Thank you for your response... Does anyone else here know a method to initialize an instance of DatabaseReference?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for either:

```
_postRef = Database.database().reference("posts")
```

Or

```
_postRef = DatabaseReference.root.child("posts")
```